# How to specify $Path items on the command line?

Tags: scripting, unix

On Unix, I can run Python scripts from the command line like this<sup>1</sup>:

```
PYTHONPATH=lib/python path/to/script.py
```

The setting of `PYTHONPATH` affects the run-time value of the `sys.path` variable, which is Python's equivalent of *Mathematica*'s `$Path` variable.

For example:

```
% PYTHONPATH=/foo:/bar:/baz python -c 'import sys; print sys.path[1:4]'
['/foo', '/bar', '/baz']
```

Is there a similar way to modify the value of the `$Path` variable from the command line when invoking WolframScripts?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Of course, I can omit the `PYTHONPATH=lib/python` "prefix" by first running `export PYTHONPATH=/absolute/path/to/lib/python`.  The form with the "prefix", however, gives me the flexibility to tailor the library path to the script, something I often find useful.</sup>

Comment: How about `mathkernel -run '$Path=...'` ?

Comment: There are two environment variables that can be used for this, MATHEMATICA_BASE and MATHEMATICA_USERBASE. With them I think you should be able to achieve what you want, although they are not exactly the same thing as PYTHONPATH. Both are documented [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConfigurationFiles.html)

Comment: @AlbertRetey: Thanks for the pointer.  After experimenting a bit with `MATHEMATICA_BASE` and `MATHEMATICA_USERBASE`, however, I concluded that *Mathematica* interprets them sufficiently differently from what I have in mind that decided to go with a different solution.  (I've posted this solution as an answer, below.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I cobbled together this hack, inspired by Ilian's comment.  Below is the content of a wrapper script, which I called `wolframscript`, and put in my `$PATH`:

```
#!/bin/bash

components='"'"${MATHEMATICAPATH//:/'", "'}"'"'
setpath=$( printf '$Path = DeleteDuplicates @ Join[{%s}, $Path];' "$components" )
interpreter=$( which WolframScript )

exec $interpreter -run "$setpath" -script "$@"
```

Now, for example, if `/tmp/test.m` is the following executable script

```
#!/usr/bin/env wolframscript

Write["stdout", ToString @ Column @ Take[$Path, 3]];
```

...I can run

```
% MATHEMATICAPATH='/yabba:/dabba:/doo' /tmp/test.m
/yabba
/dabba
/doo
```